# gh-pages branch fails to build at GitHub but runs flawlessly locally

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have two sub-modules in the *gh-pages* branch of particular project. Every time I push this project I receive this familiar message in my mail box:

> The page build failed with the following error:
>
> The submodule registered for `./updates/4.4.luna` could not be cloned.
>   Make sure it's using https:// and that it's a public repo. For more
>   information, see
>   https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-invalid-submodule.

This only refers to one of the sub-modules, even though both are configured the same way. They are both public and registered with *https://* addresses in the local repository:

```
$ git submodule foreach -q git config remote.origin.url
https://github.com/ldesousa/dsl3s.update.4.3.kepler.git
https://github.com/ldesousa/dsl3s.update.4.4.luna.git
```

I went through the trouble of installing [Jekyll](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/#troubleshooting) to run the site locally (boy, the instructions at the GitHub page are poor). And locally everything runs perfectly; Jeckyll reports no errors at all.

What else can I do to solve this? Or at least to understand why the repository is failing to build at GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some more digging I found out that the metadata in the main repository was not coinciding with that of of the sub-modules:

```
$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "updates/4.3.kepler"]
    path = updates/4.3.kepler
    url = https://github.com/ldesousa/dsl3s.update.4.3.kepler.git
[submodule "updates/4.4.luna"]
    path = updates/4.4.luna
    url = git@github.com:ldesousa/dsl3s.update.4.4.luna.git
```

So I had to correct the last URL for the *http://* version and then run:

```
git submodule sync
```